# Get access of Raspberry pi on a home network

Tags: pi-2, raspbian-jessie, windows

I have a Raspberry Pi that I connected to my laptop using an ethernet cable. Doing `ifconfig` on pi's console gives this:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:ad:a2:de
          inet addr:192.168.137.251  Bcast:192.168.137.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6e54:8c9b:cc3e:4fc2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2883 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:595 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:231246 (225.8 KiB)  TX bytes:76827 (75.0 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:200 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:200 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:16656 (16.2 KiB)  TX bytes:16656 (16.2 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:ef:73:00:3b
          inet6 addr: fe80::f7a8:d272:af9:11b8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:315 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Topology:
[image]

I ran a small web app on my RaspberryPi which runs on port 8765. So, if I open `http://192.168.137.251:8765` on my Windows machine I get 200 as the response status.

`A` is able to access the application but `B` & `C` are not able to access the application.

Following is the output of `ipconfig` on `A` to which the RaspberryPi is connected:

```
C:\Users\Animesh>ping raspberrypi.mshome.net

Pinging raspberrypi.mshome.net [192.168.137.251] with 32 bytes of
    Reply from 192.168.137.251: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
    Reply from 192.168.137.251: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
    Reply from 192.168.137.251: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
    Reply from 192.168.137.251: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.137.251:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 0ms

C:\Users\Animesh>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network #3:

       Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
       Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9d6f:d42b:9e5e:a0c9%2
       IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
       Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
       Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network #4:

       Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
       Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1836:6396:4830:81da%6
       IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.99.1
       Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
       Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

    Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

       Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
       Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

    Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

       Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
       Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::a03d:717:d2a6:254d%8
       IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.137.1
       Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
       Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

    Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

       Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
       IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : ::607e:8e7a:9493:2895
       Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : ::7029:6b37:332f:280a
       Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::607e:8e7a:9493:2895%4
       IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.4
       Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
       Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1

    Tunnel adapter isatap.{2ADA87A1-6121-441C-9CF8-3E5532A5AE0B}:

       Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
       Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

    Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 3:

       Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
       Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

    Tunnel adapter isatap.{F31CA97A-AE93-4D97-AE11-5429537A7428}:

       Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
       Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

    Tunnel adapter isatap.{0A7563CE-6A11-4C76-888F-CAF51F88933A}:

       Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
       Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

    Tunnel adapter isatap.{4C0E3C0F-AB34-41E7-BA11-E74F05E21382}:

       Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
       Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

What changes should I make in order to make

Comment: This question is seriously lacking in detail. How did you setup the network and what is the network topology?

Comment: @Milliways I have added more details to the question.

Comment: Your Pi is getting an IP address in the range `192.168.137.` (where from?). The rest of your network is running on a different LAN segment `192.168.0.` They will be unable to communicate unless you bridge them. The question is **WHY**? do you want to do this, and not just connect to your router?

Comment: Suggested  "improvement" Milliways Instead of asking WHY make some real suggestions how to fix the issue at hand.